# Searching for a word in my own posts

Tags: support, search

I wanted to search an old post of mine that contained the word "router". So I went to the stackexchange main page and looked for "user:me router". I got many results, but none of them is a post of mine: https://stackexchange.com/search?q=user%3Ame+router

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: That is a Google search box, it doesn't understand the special SE search keys.

Comment: So where can I find the search box that does understand the SE special keys?

Comment: You will have to do so on specific sites... Surely there is only a small subset of sites that you are engaged in where the use of "router" would occur?

Comment: I tried but didn't find what I was looking for, so I thought maybe a global search would find it..

Comment: Witch site you wrote this post on?

Comment: Tip: go to your SO profile, to the questions page, click the "recent deleted questions" at the bottom.

Comment: @Oded thanks! That's just what I was looking for :)

Comment: A google search for your name + "router" (both as required), yielded that link... though now deleted, only available to yourself, moderators and +10k users.